# jquery ajax error while using c# function

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I want to use jquery ajax in my project. I just run a simple ajax with code behind. I got the alert error as "500 internal error"

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.2.6.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {

         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "listprac.aspx/sayHello",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             data: "{}",
             dataType: "json",
             success: AjaxSucceeded,
             error: AjaxFailed
         });
     });
     function AjaxSucceeded(result) {
         alert(result.d);
     }
     function AjaxFailed(result) {
         alert(result.status + ' ' + result.statusText);
     }  

  </script>
```

My code behind:

```
 public static string sayHello()
    {
        return "hello ";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `aspx` pages you'll have to decorate your code-behind method with the `[WebMethod()]` attribute:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string sayHello()
{
    return "hello ";
}
```

**Edit:** `WebMethod` is within the `System.Web.Services.WebService` namespace.

Comment: You'll have to include the `System.Web.Services.WebService` namespace. I've updated my answer as well.